# jSON not exporting my array when using .getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I am trying to use a get to get information from a button and then spit out an array that is .  So far, when running this code, the `.getJSON` isn't called (when I take out the query, it works, but I can't find any problems with the query).

Here is the relevant code:

**Javascript:**

```
$.getJSON("/westcoast_map.php", // The server URL
{
    westcoast_id: $('.opener').data('westcoast_id')
}, // Data you want to pass to the server.
function (json) {

    var id = json[0];
    waypts = json[1];
    alert(id);
    console.log(waypts);

});
```

**php script** (westcoast_map.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";
$current_user = current_user();
include_once("config.php");

$westcoast_id    = $_GET['westcoast_id'];
$westcoast_array = array();
$query           = "SELECT city, state FROM users GROUP BY city";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
        $westcoast_array[$row] = "{location:" . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . ", stopover:true}";
    }
}
$data = array(
    $westcoast_id,
    $westcoast_array
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**The button**:

```
<button type="button" class="opener" data-westcoast_id="westcoast_id" onclick="calcRoute();">
    West Coast
</button>
```

Comment: I'm no PHP guy but it seems to me like you're doing some json formatting here (   $westcoast_array[$row] = "{location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true}";
)-- I don't think you should have to do this--- the json_encode should take care of it.

Comment: PHP guy here… have you browsed to the PHP handler?  Any errors? What is the output if you manually feed it $_GET params in the address bar?

Comment: I get this: Illegal offset type in <b>/nfs/c09/h04/mnt/139243/domains/crowdsets.com/html/westcoast_map.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

and I am trying to export an array within the json array ha (I want json[1] to be the created array

Comment: line 19 is the $westcoast_array[$row] = "{location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true}"; line

Comment: Looks like you are missing a key to your value for state, try: `{location:".$row['city'].", state:".$row['state'].", stopover:true}`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are missing the `key` to your `value` for state, try this:

```
if($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
    $westcoast_array[] = "{
        location:".$row['city'].", 
        state:".$row['state'].", 
        stopover:true
    }";
}
```

You are also using an array as a key, which you cannot do. Change `$westcoast_array[$row]` to `$westcoast_array[]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but I think you're making the `JSON` on your own and using `json_encode` to encode it again. Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";
$current_user = current_user();
include_once("config.php");

$westcoast_id    = $_GET['westcoast_id'];
$westcoast_array = array();
$query           = "SELECT city, state FROM users GROUP BY city";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
        $westcoast_array[] = array("location" => $row['city'], "state" => $row['state'], "stopover" => true);
    }
}
$data = array(
    $westcoast_id,
    $westcoast_array
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```